# DataContextProxy silverlight comboboxes - is there a better way?

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm-light

I'm using the datacontextproxy class defined by [Dan Wahlin](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx) to solve what seemed so very difficult for the many many hours leading up to that discovery.

I have a combobox that is bound to an `ObservableCollection<Accounts>`. The combobox also has the values: `DisplayMemberPath=AccountNumber`, and the `SelectedValue={Binding SelectedAccount}`. I then have a DataForm that has its CurrentItem property also bound to SelectedAccount. Inside my DataForm, I have a handful of fields that require additional dropdowns (AcctCode, UsageCode, etc). To mitigate the binding issues I ran into inside of a DataForm, I implemented the datacontextproxy, allowing me to set the ItemsSource of my cbobox to `{Binding Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}, Path=DataSource.AccountCodes}"`. This is working great in terms of the end result.

Before stumbling onto this, I really struggled with this find. I'm not using a domaincontext, so I couldn't use Kyle Mcllelans ComboBoxex, nor could I use the vast majority of solutions offered. I did try to create an instance of my ViewModel as a local resource in my View, but a) I felt dirty in terms of MVVM, and b) It failed to create a new VM instance, as my VM requires a number of service references to be passed in on construct.

In any case, I'm simply wondering if there's a way I should be doing this that's either more performant, more MVVM, more maintainable, more bestest'er, etc etc.

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scott I also have settled on using the DataContextProxy. I think use of it still provides a good MVVM solution where the view only has knowledge of the VM via binding or commanding.

I see use of it as a temporary solution until Silverlight 5 ships. In Silverlight 5 ancestor binding is introduced which will provide more flexibility in data binding.

Comment: I heart you so very much for the SL5 info. I hadn't had time to look it up, but man I'm excited :-D